# Attempt to read property "Name" on array on my laravel login

Tags: php

Hello i have been getting a Attempt to read property "Name" on array error on my login for laravel. we have been trying different ways to get it working but so far no success.

```
@extends("Layout")
 <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo '<p>TEST</p>';
    $sql = DB::select('select * from users where Name = ?', [$_POST["txtuser"]]);
    if(!$sql->Name == "") {
        echo 'No user found!';
    } else {
        if($sql->password == $_POST["txtpass"]) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
            header("location: home.blade.php");
        } else {
            echo 'wrong password!';
        }
    }
}
?>

<div class="card2">
    <div class="center">
        <button><a href="{{url('/home')}}" >Home</a> </button>
        <button> <a href="{{url ('/b2b') }}" >Business to business</a> </button>
        <button><a href="{{url ('/b2c') }}" >Business to consumer </a> </button>
        <button><a href="{{url ('/c2c')}}" >Consumer to consumer</a> </button>
        <button><a href="{{url ('login-system/login')}}" >Login</a> </button>
        <button><a href="{{url ('/store')}}">Store</a></button>
</div>


    <H1>Login</H1>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
        @csrf
    <input type="text" name="txtuser" value='' />
    <input type="password" name="txtpass" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="submit"/>
</form>




</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use `var_dump($sql)` to see what it contains. maybe you are just selecting the wrong item from your object. I'm not certain but i don't think it's with a capital letter either

Comment: If the query returns no matches, what do you get in `$sql`? Further, `!` has higher precedence than `==` so `if(!$sql->Name == "")` probably doesn't do what you think it does. And **never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to loop through your select first. If I'm not mistaken even if you select a specific user you will get an array back.

example:

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users');
 
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

or you could do something try to get the first item from the array that is returned and store it in a variable `$user` and then you could use `$user->name`

also it's not a bad thing to count the items returned before using them. It could be that you have 0 items returned and in that cause you can show user not found (i quickly wrote the code below without testing)

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where Name = ?', [$_POST["txtuser"]]);
    if(count($users) == 0) {
        echo 'No user found!';
    }
```

also it would be a good thing to include your password check into the sql statement itself. It's better practice to check username and password together instead of saying if a user exists or not